# Combobox doesnt initialize with SelectedValue WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding, combobox

Having issues getting my Combobox to Initialize with the current selecteditem.

ClinicList returns `ObservableCollection<Clinic>`

```
      <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ClinicList}}"
 DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClinic, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></ComboBox>
```

My ComboBox is within a listview bound to an employee. An employee can have multiple Clinics assigned.

```
public class Employee{ 
...
public ObservableCollection<ClinicView> EmployeeClinics { get; set; }
}

public class ClinicView:INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private Clinic selectedClinic;
        public Clinic SelectedClinic {
            get { return selectedClinic; }
            set {
                selectedClinic = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedClinic");
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
public class Clinic{
   public int ClinicId{get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;
}
```

The combobox shows as blank when first loaded, and will have the correct # of clinics per Employee as assigned. The combobox drop down has the correct Clinics in it, and when I select one, it replaces the blank combobox text and updates the employee correctly.

My question is why doesnt the Combobox Initially fill with correct text and is blank?

[image]

**Edit:**
ClinicList is being set via the ODP in window.resources

```
 public static ObservableCollection<Clinic> GetClinicList() {
//gets list of clinics from db with ID
}

 <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetClinicList"
                            ObjectType="{x:Type local:MappingGenerators}"
                            x:Key="ClinicList">
        </ObjectDataProvider>
```

Comment: Are you setting the `selectedClinic` property during initialization?

Comment: Can you please show where you are declaring ClinicList?

Comment: Yes, just confirmed. I wouldnt even have blank comboboxes if not, right? @SaagarEliasJacky

Comment: @markokstate if the `selectedClinic` is not set, the ComboBox won't show anything selected; doesn't mean the ComboBox will not be initialized. I think the `selectedClinic` property is being set as null during initialization and so not showing up...

Comment: If I break during runtime my Employee.EmployeeClinics contains the items I expect to see. I'm wondering if its with the Combobox SelectedValue/SelectedValuePath options?

Answer (score 4):

Found this post to be a life saver.

https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/comboboxs-selecteditem-not-displaying/

Here are the key passages:

> The problem is simple: By default WPF compares SelectedItem to each
>   item in the ItemsSource by reference, meaning that unless the
>   SelectedItem points to the same item in memory as the ItemsSource
>   item, it will decide that the item doesn’t exist in the ItemsSource
>   and so no item gets selected.
>
> To work around this, you can either use the ComboBox’s SelectedValue
>   and SelectedValuePath to set the SelectedItem by Value instead of by
>   Item